# Multiple sum of values using xpath

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

My input is an xpath that points to a node with value that i want to sum.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("XML/Cat/Item/Cost");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

<XML>
  <Cat>   
    <Item>
        <Cost>12</Cost>
    </Item>    
    <Item>
        <Cost>10</Cost>
    </Item>    
  </Cat>
  <Cat>   
    <Item>
        <Cost>4</Cost>
    </Item>    
    <Item>
        <Cost>3.2</Cost>
    </Item>    
    <Item>
        <Cost>8.2</Cost>
    </Item> 
  </Cat>
</XML>
```

NodeList contains all the values that I can sum but I would like to sum per `<cat>` section.
12+10

4+3.2+8.2

Can it be achieved using dom and xpath?

Answer (score -1):

XPath will only return atomic values (numbers, booleans or strings) or node sets that it takes from the document it selects from.

Here what you want is not an atomic value (you want several sums, not one). And it's not something that's already in your XML document (the XML document contains no sum).

So no, it's not possible using just XPath.

You need to iterate over all your `<Cat>` elements, and for each of them calculate the sum with an XPath expression.

Comment: No. It's not true. You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369612/multiple-sum-of-values-using-xpath/49369911#49369911) - this is pure XPath solution and this is how [sum() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256160(v=vs.110).aspx) works.

Comment: @Andersson your answer only works, or even is valid syntax, with XPath 2.0 or more. That's not what OP is using, nor is it smart to assume it would considering the current state of adoption.

Comment: Once more WRONG! `sum()` is [XPath 1.0 function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum)!

Comment: @Andersson which is why I took the extra step of pointing out to you that your *syntax* is wrong in XPath 1.0, it's not just the choice of function. And for crying out loud, just test it instead of insisting it's correct

Comment: @Andersson I guess you could try to match the grammar and notice it doesn't

Comment: Totally correct as for me. What exactly is wrong with it? Can you share any arguments? For now I see no point in your claims

Comment: @Andersson comments are ill-designed to mathematically demonstrate the absence of a matching path in a grammar, and even if they weren't that's a time investment I find ridiculous considering the alternative: take any XPath testing that will only accept XPath 1.0, and notice your syntax isn't accepted, in the same way as OP described in response to your answer. You could also have a look at XPath 1.0's data model and notice, like I said in my answer, it has no way to represent what you're trying to get with your xpath.